# How to Show Interstitial ads when back Button Pressed Android

Tags: android, ads, android-fragmentactivity, interstitial

Hye friends ! I need some help from you guys regarding my android app. Basically my android project is fragment tab where I want to show Interstitial ads when user click on back button before closing app.

Kindly check out my coding below and help me to sort out this question as quick as you can thank you :)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/01"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/02"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/03"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/04"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/05"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/06"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/07"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/08"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/09"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/10"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/11"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/12"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/13"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/14"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/15"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/16"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/17"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/18"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/19"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/20"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/21"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/22"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/23"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/24"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/25"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/26"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/27"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/28"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/29"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/30"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/31"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/32"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/33"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/34"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/35"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/36"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/37"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/38"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/39"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/40"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/41"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/42"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/43"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/44"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/45"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/46"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/47"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/48"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/49"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/50"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/51"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/52"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/53"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/54"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/55"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/56"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/57"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/58"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/59"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/60"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/61"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/62"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/63"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/64"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/65"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/66"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/67"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/68"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/69"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/70"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/71"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/72"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/73"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/74"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/75"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/76"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/77"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/78"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ashaar/79"));


    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }


    });
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void sharevia(MenuItem item) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.islamichub.dil.jalay";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.islamichub.dil.jalay");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}

public void rating(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.islamichub.dil.jalay")));
}

public void findmore(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:IslamicHub")));
}

public void aboutme(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.fb.com/topitideas")));
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffff00"
    app:tabTextColor="#000000"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Please load ad Instance in onCreate() method. So, that you can prefetch ad without loading. 
And write down it like ..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    showAdvertisement();
}

private void showAdvertisement() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

private void loadInterstitialAd() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("************");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                finish();
            }
        });
        loadInterstitialAd();

Comment: Do like this in onCreate() method. To create interstitialAd you need to go through google Admob doc.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are standing on main activity and there is no any activity in stack.You need to override onBackPressed() method and add the code for interstetial add in onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Interstitial code goes here
}
```

For adding interstitial code or code help refer below link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial

Answer (score 0):

This is against policies and you risk being limited.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-user-launches-app%2Cdisallowed-example-user-exits-app%2Cdisallowed-example-recurring-interstitials%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitials-that-impact-navigation